# latexmk / imakeidx interoperational efficiency

Tags: compiling, indexing, latexmk, imakeidx

`imakeidx` and `latexmk` are two of my favorite utilities of all TeX-time, especially in the face of book-size compilations (super thanks @egreg and @John Collins!). Apart from ease of producing multiple indices, one of the most useful properties of `imakeidx` is in-document compilation index sub-compilation (how I wish `glossaries` and `biblatex` could be extended to behave the same way!)

Given MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

This.\index{this}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

`makeindex` is invoked once midway during straightforward `latex` compilation. However, when using `latexmk -recorder (etc.)`, `latexmk` ignores the new `.ind` file that `imakeidx` produces half-way through and invokes `makeindex` on the `.idx` file all over again.

Of course, this inefficiency is hardly noticeable with this toy MWE. But given many-filed book-size documents with multiple large indices, `biblatex`/`biber`, multiple `glossaries` and several tocs necessitating several passes before reaching completion, the extra work that `latexmk` creates (rather than eliminates) tests my sense of elegance (and sometimes my patience) greatly.

How, then, can I improve `latexmk`'s over-eagerness to invoke `makeindex` in documents using `imakeidx`? I'm hoping for some simple rules to add to my `.latexmkrc`. I am particularly interested in keeping the number of `makeindex` invocations to a minimum across multiple passes (not shown with this MWE) -- say, to a maximum of two invocations per any index file.

[[ Bonus points for extending `glossaries` and/or `biblatex` capability for in-document compilation a la `imakeidx`'s brand of `\write18` magic. ; ) ]]

Comment: `Arara` is a candidate worth trying for jobs like this. It is easily configureable.

Comment: @Harish — thanks for that. `Arara` certainly looks like a useful tool (kudos also for its tremendously readable manual. I wish many others could be so good — `biblatex` manual authors are you listening!??). Still, I'm struggling to see how it might fit the bill without make-like dependency-conditioned compilation. To me, it seems ideal for configuring "straight through" processing, but, without diving into Java coded rules, it doesn't solve my problem – efficient dependency-constrained assembly pipeline automation. However, please correct me if it is up to this and I'll take another look.

Comment: The added advantage  of arara is the author and his friends (@Paulo Cereda, @Marcodaniel and Brent) are very generous and helpful. You can get good help here.

Comment: @Harish, yes, very true. Plus they know how to write a really great user manual. Trouble is, for all its other graces, `arara` just can't solve the problem asked above. BTW, in fairness, `latexmk`'s author John Collins is equally active, generous etc. in this and other fora. : )

Answer (score 11):

I don't see any way of configuring the current version of `latexmk` to prevent it doing the extra runs.  Not only is `makeindex` run a second time by `latexmk`, but so is `latex`, so the run time is doubled, which is a bad penalty on a large document.

To correct this needs changes in `latexmk` itself.  There is enough information in the `.log` file for `latexmk` to determine that the `.ind` file was made during the run of `latex` before it was read, and therefore to show that the extra runs are not needed.  I've added this to my list of enhancements for a future version of `latexmk`.

Comment: I guess my question was that supposing I use `imakeidx` for all index (`.idx`, `.ind`) file production, would there be any way of preventing `latexmk` from invoking the `makeindex` program by configuring a rule for this in my local `.latexmkrc`? I.e., instruct `latexmk` to completely ignore `.idx` -> `.ind` production. I've tried to achieve this by configuring/removing local dependencies rules, but haven't got very far.

Answer (score 5):

Not to take away anything from John's answer, adding `$makeindex = "touch -m %D";` to the local `.latexmkrc` produces automated workflow with nearly minimal overhead. In which case, on my system with this example, `latex` is only run once. I.e., this is (nearly) as efficient as things can ever get. The proviso, of course, is that `imakeidx` with `\write18` enabled is always used — not a problem in my case.

(*) Windows users can pick up a copy of `touch.exe` in any modern `gnu` distribution.

Comment: That's the case on the first run of `latexmk`.  But if you change the file by something that affects the index (e.g., by adding `\index{that}`), and you then rerun `latexmk`, you will find it does a second run of `latex`.  The problem is that the `.ind` file changed between the start and end of the first run of `latex`; that is an indication that the output file is out-of-date.

Comment: @John, very true. However, of little impact with non-trivial documents, i.e., most real-world docs needing multiple compiles (where second runs will be happening anyway). Given `latexmk`'s `$makeindex` command redefined above, the burden of a second `touch` is negligible, and much less than extra invocations of `makeindex` (esp. in multi-indiced docs). Certainly not ideal, of course, and much uglier than were `latexmk` to acquire a `-makeindex-` command line switch a la the most useful `-bibtex-` option and/or some more programmatic way to turn off `makeindex` dependencies processing.